# Unable to use objects from a module in sys.modules

Tags: python, django, python-import

Because of circular imports a want to load a module this way:

```
try:
    from ..foo import serializers as foo_serializers
except ImportError:
    import sys
    foo_serializers = sys.modules['app.foo.serializers']
```

When I use the loaded module in a class definition like this, it says `app.foo.serializers has no attribute FooSerializer` although it definitely has:

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    foo_field = foo_serializers.FooSerializer()
```

But when I use `foo_serializers.FooSerializer` in a class function it works. What does it mean? Are modules in `sys.modules` fully loaded in the time when the class definition is loaded? What could be a problem here?